# GTSpeed SUPEE 6788 - Admin Route

Tags: supee-6788

I've read through a lot of the posts about 404s after installing SUPEE 6788 and really have tried to replicate the steps for this extension (GTSpeed) but I have been unable to action the correct steps to get this working.

I hope someone can help me?

I used the SUPEE 6788 tool and it identified the following :

Found route tag 'gtspeed'. Original route XML:

```
<gtspeed>
   <use>admin</use>
   <args>
      <module>GT_Speed</module>
      <frontName>gtspeed</frontName>
   </args>
</gtspeed>
```

To be replaced with:

```
<adminhtml>
   <args>
      <modules>
         <gtspeed before="Mage_Adminhtml">GT_Speed_Adminhtml</gtspeed>
      </modules>
    </args>
</adminhtml>
```

So I went ahead and did the above change to config.xml

Then it also identified:

```
ERROR: /home/psadmin99/public_html/ps-test/app/code/community/GT/Speed/controllers/Adminhtml does not exist! This module's admin routes must be corrected manually.
```

So I made the following folder and put the file that was once in the controllers folder into this new folder:

```
/app/code/community/GT/Speed/controllers/Adminhtml/gtspeed/InfoController.php
```

But I'm not sure what to do next?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your folder name should be `Gtspeed` (note, uppercase G). The class name of that file will need to be corrected to `Gt_Speed_Adminhtml_Gtspeed_InfoController`.

After that, it's a question of fixing any routes that reference the old path. The old routes probably look like `gtspeed/info`, possibly with other stuff after. There are a lot of different places this could appear:

`etc/adminhtml.xml` in `action` tags
`etc/config.xml` in `action` tags
Any .php or .phtml file from the module containing getUrl(...)

You may also have to fix the admin layout handles, in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/gtspeed.xml` (or such). `<gtspeed_info_` would become `<adminhtml_gtspeed_info_`.

...And you have to be careful to only change admin URL references, or you risk breaking frontend links or pages in the process. It's quite the process.

All the best.